# How Windows differentiates between Copied files and Created files

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-server-2008-r2

I am looking for a bit of advice on how Windows file system differentiates between files that are copied(copy and pasted from another location) and files that are created (a new file created in a a folder).

A bit of background to this so it makes more sense: I have an application that is used to move files. The application will monitor a directory and when a file is placed in the directory it will move it elsewhere. However, I am having issues where the application will not pick up a file that is created within the monitored directory but will pick up files that have been created else where and are copied into the monitored directory.

Any advice on how Windows differentiates, or if it does at all, would be greatly appreciated.

This is running on  Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. I can't dig into the code and see what is going on under the hood unfortunately, so need to get an idea of the difference if any there would be.

Comment: I don't think it makes the distinction.

Comment: How do you create the file on your directoy? Save it directly there, or do you create the file, edit, then save? The problem might be on this logic, as I am most certain that there is no distinction made by the OS on a copied file over a "regular" one.

Comment: So the process would be to create the file and then write data into that file. Would that have an effect on how windows would identify the file? Bearing in mind it doesn't make a difference if the file is blank, it still seems to look at the files differently.

Comment: Windows should not have anything to do with this. The problem is likely on the application reading the folder. Can you provide more information on it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, its pretty much a black box, I know I am asking for a lot not being able to provide any insight into the app, but just wanted to get an idea if there was any clear distinction made between the two files that are placed in the folder.

Comment: If you create the file in memory and use something like (Save As...) to save it to the directory, does it work? I reckon that when you create a file on the folder, the application will detect it immediately and, since it is blank, won't do anything with it. Then when you finish creating the file (save), it won't trigger the application to check that file again. Does that make sense?

Comment: The monitoring logic is probably using ReadDirectoryChangesW or FindFirstChangeNotification, and (due to a bug) is only detecting certain types of change.  A copy operation may well be different to a create operation, depending on the specific implementations.  How are you creating the files, e.g., does your own code create them, or a particular third-party application?  You could use Process Monitor to see exactly what is happening at the file system level.

Answer (score 1):

The filesystems don't know the operation of "copying" the file. Any copying is a sequence of file open/read/write/close operations. The same applies to moving to the different filesystem. Moving within the same filesystem, though, is an operation native to the filesystems and it can be done with one command to the filesystem.

Now about your problem. Most likely you catch the creation of the file (before the data is written), and when your application reacts, the file is still opened for writing. So you need to wait until the file is closed. 
Depending on how you do monitoring, such waiting is done in different ways. In filesystem filters you wait for file close operation. With .NET FileSystemWatcher there's no way to track file close operation, but I saw a couple of tricks here on StackOverflow (don't have a link though, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

- A file existing in D: drive, from creation

[image: A file existing in D: drive, from creation]

- The same file which was copied to E: drive

[image: The same file which was copied to E: drive]

As you can see, the file which was copied to E: drive, has a creation time as the latest, when it was copied to and the modification time as the last modification time for that file in previous location.

So I guess this illustrates, how windows differentiates between copied files and created files.

Comment: If you modify the file inplace it will also update the "modified" date. I don't think this is a distinction on an arbitraty "copied" vs "created" file.

Comment: I experimented with a file and added that as the illustration, so that we would know about how windows differentiates.

Comment: If you were to write a program to list all copied files on your file system. How would you do it? You cannot just use the information about created vs modified dates, as that does not guarantee us that this file is modified.

Comment: I guess what OP is trying to ask is if there is a flag or any different treatment Windows makes to copied files, in a way that OP's application wouldn't be able to see it when it is present on the target folder. To that my answer would be "there is no difference".